# Vertically centered, absolute positioned element only displaying correctly in Chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a vertical navigation section on my website, which remains on the far left of the screen, and vertically in the centre. I'm also trying to make it responsive to screen height. I've done this by setting the font height in vh. It works just fine in Chrome, but in IE and Firefox the whole element is stuck to the top of the page. I'm a bit new to web design, any help would be appreciated!

HTML

```
<nav><ul>
<a href=#><li>home</li></a>
<a href=#><li>about</li></a>
<a href=#><li>work</li></a>
<a href=#><li>contact</li></a></ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
bottom:0;
display: table;
font-size:7vh;
height: auto;
line-height:15vh;
margin:auto;
overflow: auto;
padding:3vh;
padding-right:5vh;
position:absolute;
top:0;
vertical-align:central;
z-index:1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vertical-middle:center` doesnt really work in some browsers like Internet Explorer (not even the IE 8 beta). Just use `margin-top:60x` instead of `vertical-align:center`. [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/kdQ6c/).

**CSS:**

```
nav {
bottom:0;
display: table;
font-size:7vh;
height: auto;
line-height:15vh;
margin:auto;
overflow: auto;
padding:3vh;
padding-right:5vh;
position:absolute;
top:0;
margin-top:60px;
z-index:1}
```

Refer to this [blog](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) for vertical centering with css.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted it to be responsive and shrink so i've actually set the margin-top to 15vh but I didn't realise vertical-align wasn't supported everywhere. Thanks again!